# Taking values from an array from the arguments object then returning the answer with a for loop

Tags: function, loops, printing

Thank you for taking the time to read this !
What the end result I am aiming for is learning how to print all the result by taking the values put in the functions arguments object.

```
enter code here

function solve(args) {
    var numb = +args.length,
        numbBySeven = numb % 7 === 0,
        numbByFive = numb % 5 === 0,
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < numb; index++) {
        if (numbBySeven && numbByFive) {
            return 'true ' + numb;  //print this 
        } else {
            return 'false ' + numb; // print this 
        }
    }
}
console.log("solve ", solve(['35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35'])); // from this
```

Comment: what language are you doing this in? Different languages have different methods. This _appears_ to be javascript?

Answer (score 0):

**do you want similar to this?**

```
function solve(args) {
    var numb = args.length;
for(var j = 0; j<numb;j++){
        var numbBySeven = numb[j] % 7 === 0
        var numbByFive = numb[j] % 5 === 0

        if (numbBySeven && numbByFive) {
            console.log( 'true ' + numb[j])  //print this
        } else {
            console.log( 'flase ' + numb[j]) // print this
        }

}
}

console.log(solve(['35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35']))
```

Comment: so what you did was made a loop that goes from j to args.length then, you checked every index j if it is divisible by 5 and 7 then the conditional statement verifying true or false, and you print it with every index . Yea I wanted this. Thanks for the quick answer.